# How to make SQL query based on CheckedListBox selection

Tags: vb.net

I have a `CheckedListBox1` and its selections create an SQL query to fill the DataGridView. Unfortunately, it does not give me anything, probably my SQL select statement is not correct or I am passing an array of string values which is not correct

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

    Dim i As Integer
    'xx is an array of string, used to store checkedlistbox selection
    Dim xx() As String
    Dim sqlstr2 As String


    For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step i + 1

        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then

            xx(i) = CheckedListBox1.SelectedValue(i)

        End If
    Next
    sqlstr2 = "SELECT * From Table WHERE [TagName] in (' "%, "' '"& [xx] & "' )"'
    SQL.RunQuery(sqlstr2)

    If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        DataGridView1.DataSource = SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you actually look at the value `sqlstr2` to see whether it made sense? I have to wonder because you seem to think that it's a good idea not to show it to us. I suggest that you read [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298).

Comment: You need to take loook at [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2). And use it for `[xx]` with `,` as delimiter. Currently you are passing array as it is, it will be treated as single value and multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you declare another array check MS docs. I don't believe you want to run your query every time you check or uncheck a box. I moved the code to a Button which can be clicked when the user has settled on checks.

Fortunately, the CheckedListBox has a CheckedItems collection to loop through. In the loop we build a string to use in the In clause of the sql statement.

Check the Immediate Window to see that the sql statement is what you intend

I can only assume that the rest of your code involves your own custom class and methods. I commented it out so I could test the code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim inClause As String = ""
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        inClause &= "'" & item.ToString & "',"
    Next
    'Get rid of the final comma
    inClause = inClause.TrimEnd(","c)
    Dim sqlstr2 = "SELECT * From Table WHERE [TagName] in (" & inClause & ");"
    Debug.Print(sqlstr2)
    'Sql.RunQuery(sqlstr2)
    'If Sql.SQLDataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    '    DataGridView1.DataSource = Sql.SQLDataset.Tables(0)
    'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well I don't have a button to do this. I only have checkedlistbox, the  selection will write an SQL query and will populate from the the SQL database. is there any other way, I can achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand. Can't you add a button?

Comment: No there is not an option for me for button. There is a DataViewGrid on the Form and once I click on a specific column, Checkedlistbox will pop up and based on the selection of items in checkedlistbox, it should write SQL query and get only that data (Strictly on selection)

Comment: Well, then move the code back to the ItemCheck event but you will be running sql.RunQuery very often.